# CSV to MySQL using PHP -- change value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a company that delivers there product feed with all details about stock, price etc as a CSV file. I use the following script to update my database with that CSV file:

```
<?php
echo "Update wordt uitgevoerd.... <br><br>";

$mysqlHost = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";

$link = mysql_connect($mysqlHost, $user, $password) 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$handle = fopen("update.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
$model = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[0]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[5]);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[7]);
mysql_select_db("wowtoxco_oc1", $link);

$result = mysql_query(
    "UPDATE oc_product SET price='$price', quantity='$quantity' 
     WHERE model='$model'"
) or die(mysql_error());
echo $model . " - art.nr. locked -> ";
echo $price . " prijs updated -> ";
echo $quantity . " voorraad updated.<br>";
}

fclose($handle);
mysql_close($link);

echo "<br>Script uitgevoerd.";
?>
```

**The problem:**
The price in the CSV file is e.g 1,25 where as OpenCart expects 1.25.

Is there a way for the script to replace the comma with a dot before the query runs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I took off the CSV tag because I think the question is simply about PHP, but if I'm wrong, we should put it back.  So, you just want to convert the string by replacing a comma with a period -- is that right?

Comment: Hello Smandoli, your correct the tag wasn't actualy related to the actual problem. And i think that's right altho i am not 100 percent sure what a string is! I do want the comma changed to a period in the CSV file using the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$price = str_replace(",", ".", $price);

// here your run your query
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ..." ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a bunch furas! (I don't know how to mark the answer as the correct one, as this is my first time asking rather than reading stack overflow, someone feel free to do so!)